# how to convert string to double in php without using doubleval function?

Tags: php, double, typecasting-operator

I have a string value $a=10. I have to convert to double value before storing. how to convert string to double in php.

I tried adding 0.00 to the $a. i.e $a= $a+0.00; But it doesn't work

Comment: `$a=10;` is not a string but rather an Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this

```
   $a = 10;
   echo number_format($a, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you sir its working !!

Answer (score 0):

You can try doubleval() which is an alias of the floatval function that get float value of a variable.

```
<?php
$a = doubleval($a);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: got you sir, is this better ?

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't worrk

Comment: The question title is "how to convert string to double in php without using doubleval function"

Answer (score 0):

You can quick-cast the variable or the operation (or both)

`$a = (float) $a + 0.00`

`$a = (float) $a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `floatval`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

```
<?php
$a=10;
$floatVal = floatval($a);
?>
```